# The variable I reset in my forloop does not change

Tags: javascript, mysql, loops, for-loop, global-variables

```
var dragcar;
dragelem = { name: 'foo', rowid: '1', kw: '50', convoy: '1' };
if (dragelem.name.length > 0) {
  //get dragcar
  resdb.forEach((worker) => {
    //find matching worker in db
    if (worker.name == dragelem.name) {
      //worker has no carid
      if (worker.carid == null) {
        dragcar = null;
      } else {
        dragcarid = worker.carid;
        connection.query("SELECT name FROM cars WHERE carid = ?;", [dragcarid], (errdb2, resdb2) => {
          //error while selecting data
          if (errdb2) {
            console.log(errdb2);
          } else {
            dragcar = resdb2[0].name;
          }
        })
      }
    }
  })
}
```

So if I log the variable after my loop, it says that it's undefined. I would be very thankful for an idea how to fix this.

best regards

Comment: Database queries are asynchronous. Are you waiting for them to complete before trying to log the variable? Try putting your `console.log` inside the `else` statement, right after `dragcar = ...`

Comment: well I need the value outside of the loop so I can make a new db entry with it.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is correct (`dragcar` will hold the value of `resdb2[0].name` from the last iteration of the loop where it is set) -- the problem is that the code never runs, probably due to `resdb` being empty or `worker.name` never being equal to `dragelem.name`.

**Edit** - didn't notice the async thing.  As pointed out in a comment, the query callback will run after the current task (including the entire `forEach` call and subsequent code) completes.  You could move the relevant code into the callback as suggested, or use `await` with promises to make the code follow a more synchronous-looking flow.

Comment: the db is not empty and I really need the variable outside of the loop so I can start a update-query after the loop (I have this loop twice because in the first loop I set dropcar and in the second one I set dragcar, and because the value can also be null, I have to check it an if-statement before). hope it's understandable how I write it.

Comment: This is an example of what's known as "callback hell".  To deal with this you really need something like the async library (https://github.com/caolan/async), `async`/`await`, or a promise library like Bluebird (https://npmjs.com/package/bluebird).  If you don't want to use promises then async is the way to go.  It has functions for doing async versions of `map`, `forEach`, etc, and for stringing functions together so that the next one runs when the previous one and all its callbacks have finished (`series`).

Comment: thanks for your answer mate, am going to try this. hope it works with this.